# Casting type parameter

Tags: c#, generics, casting

The title might be a bit vague, but what I want is to achieve this, but then without using the extra lambda in the create method:

```
public class Wrapper
{
    public static Wrapper Create<T>(Func<T, bool> someFunc) where T : Stream
    {
        return new Wrapper(a => someFunc(a as T)); // Works, but lambda
        return new Wrapper((Func<Stream, bool>)(object)someFunc); // Runtime error
        return new Wrapper((Func<Stream, bool>)someFunc); // Compile error
    }

    Func<Stream, bool> _someFunc;
    private Wrapper(Func<Stream, bool> someFunc)
    {
        _someFunc = someFunc;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do this, if so, how?

**EDIT: The stream class is just as example.**

In my code I won't be using a stream class, and as for why the type-parameter, because it's returned from a generic method, which is an extension method.

Also, the call will always be type-safe, I wanted to make the 'Wrapper' class itself generic, but then it'd be unable to add it to generic collections, because they'd have different type-parameters.

Comment: Say what? If the constructor takes a lambda, you'll need to provide one. What is it you want to avoid, and why?

Comment: Why do you need your method to be generic?

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea what you are doing. You don't show us how _someFunc is used, but if it i used in a context where a `Stream` instance can be passed in, your code most likely will break. What if `T` was a `FileStream` and the user passes in a `NetworkStream`?

Comment: I want to avoid a lambda around a lambda. Why, just because it seems unnecessary to have a lambda around a lambda of a type that just an implementation of a base class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do what you want without a lambda. A `Func<Stream, bool>` must accept any type of `Stream` as a parameter, so a method that takes a `T` (which is a specific kind of `Stream`) is not compatible with the signature of `Func<Stream, bool>`

Anyway, in the code you posted the generic parameter is completely useless; so just remove it, and make the method non-generic.

Comment: It'd just move the problem, since the implementations actually return this type. So it'll have to be converted one way or another. If you see the last part of my post, then you can see that it's actually a list of a generic type, but that type differs for each entry in the list. .Net 4.0 dynamics should solve this too, but I can only use 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be casted (even with contravariance support) because it is not a safe cast.

If I have a function that acts on FileStream, then try to pass it into Wrapper, I've passed it in as a function that claims it can act on *any* Stream.  If I then invoke that function from within Wrapper using a MemoryStream, for instance, then the delegate binding fails.  The `Func<Stream, bool>` is not really a `Func<Stream, bool>` at all.

---

if you want to make Wrapper generic (`Wrapper<T>`), you might consider exposing a non-generic interface `IWrapper` implemented by the generic. This way you can create a collection of `IWrapper` instances and expose the functionality that is valid to perform on any `Wrapper<T>`, while still maintaining type-safety inside each instance.